# STM32G0 Seems to output 0.77 V on the input pin when set to high impedance and nothing else is connected to it, why does this happen?

Tags: stm32, input, input-impedance, high-impedance

Currently I have an a pin on an STM32 set to be an input and floating (high impedance). When the device it was measuring from was powered down and nothing was going on I was measure about 0.35 V on both a DMM and scope at the input to this pin. I thought maybe this was coming from the device it was connected to somehow, so I removed said device, so the only thing left connected to that input pin was a small filtering resistor and cap. I then started measuring 0.77 V at the input pin. Where is this voltage coming from?

It seems to be consistent (i.e. isn't randomly floating between 0 and 3.3). If I set it to pull up I see 3.3V and Pull down I see 0 V.

Comment: What voltage would you expect it to be? It is a part of a certain circuit, and Hi-Z does not mean it is 0 potential or something. It just means that it is - high impedance between it and the circuit.

Comment: Post full schematics. There may be some current leaking via other pins, so it's the unpowered device that gets power somewhere and drives the pin to some voltage. The MCU will not have enough leakage to pull the input voltage up so much that a scope can't load it down. Being connected to unpowered chips is always a situation that needs to be handled with extreme care to stop leakages and save power, or rather, not to blow up chips.